# Uniformly Integrability of $M_{t\land \tau}$

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, brownian-motion, stopping-times, uniform-integrability

I want to show the uniformly integrability of a solution to the Skorokhod embedding Problem. i.e. given a centered probability measure $\mu$ with finite first moment, we want to construct a stopping time tau such that for a Brownian motion $B_t$ the stopped process $B_\tau \sim \mu$. Moreover, $B_{\tau \land t}$ should be  uniformly integrable.

I have constructed the stopping time $\tau$ via Azema-Yor's solution but I struggle showing the uniform integrability of $B_{\tau \land t}$

While constructing we have a sequence of stopping times $\tau_n$ such that $B_{\tau_n} \sim \mu_n$ and $\mu_n$ converges to $\mu$.

So the problem consists of:

Given a Brownian motion $M_t$ and a stopping time $\tau$, such that $\mathbb {E} [\tau] = \mathbb {E}[M^2_{\tau}]$, moreover I know $\mathbb {E}[|M_\tau|] < \infty$ and that there 
exists a sequence of $\tau_n$ converging to $\tau$ and for each $n \quad \mathbb {E} [M^2_{\tau_n}] < \infty$.

I want to show that the family $\{M_{t \land \tau}| t \ge 0\}$ is uniformly integrable.

I have been trying show that $\mathbb {E}[|M_{t \land  \tau}|1_{\{|M_{t \land  \tau}|\ge K\}}]  < \infty $.

For this I tried to show that  $\mathbb {E}\left[|M_{t \land  \tau}|1_{\{|M_{t \land  \tau}|\ge K\}}\right]  \le \mathbb {E}[|M_{ \tau}|1_{\{|M_{  \tau}|\ge K\}}] $ where one easily could find for any suitable $\epsilon$ a K such that the expectation is smaller.

Thank you for hints.

Comment: Do you assume that $\mathbb{E}(\tau)<\infty$?

Comment: No I do not assume that $\mathbb E[\tau] < \infty$

Comment: I think one could assume it and then solve if from the construction of the $\tau_n$ by a monotone convergence Argument.

Comment: Well, but as far as I can see you don't assume $\mathbb{E}(\tau_n)<\infty$.... ?

Comment: I do, I see I unfortunately forgot the square in $\mathbb E[M^2_{\tau_n}]< \infty $ from which by optional stopping Theorem follows that $\mathbb E[\tau_n] < \infty$

Comment: @lukas $\mathbb{E}[M^2_{\tau_n}]<\infty$ does not imply $\mathbb{E}[\tau_n]<\infty.$

Comment: @lukas I mean, in general you cannot draw this conclusion. Of course, if you *know* that the optional stopping theorem is valid for your stopping time $\tau_n$, then of course you are right.

Comment: Ah, I see, and yes the stopping theorem is valid for the $\tau_n$

Comment: @lukas Do you have a specific application in mind? In this case, it would be much easier if you include **all** the information to your question (...and not only the part which you think is important for this question).

Comment: Yes I do have a concrete application to it and added them.